# Group by while using "case when" statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, case-when

I am trying to group by name in the sql statement below.  The same FirstName can be entered into the system multiple times.  I want to group by row to total the over_short hours by person(FirstName).

```
select FirstName,
case 
when managers.title = 'GM' then isnull([TotalSalaryHours],0)-90
when managers.title = '1st' then isnull([RegHours],0)+isnull([OTHours],0)
+isnull([PTO],0)+isnull([HolidayHours],0)-70

End As Over_Short

from Hours
join Managers on managers.Manager_id = hours.manager_id
group by  
FirstName,
case 
when managers.title = 'GM' then isnull([TotalSalaryHours],0)-90
end,
case 
when managers.title = '1st' then isnull([RegHours],0)+isnull([OTHours],0)
+isnull([PTO],0)+isnull([HolidayHours],0)-70
end
, totalsalaryhours, reghours, othours, PTO, holidayhours, totalhourlyhours, title
```

thanks,

Comment: It's unclear what your problem is, you're grouping by many fields not in your `SELECT` list, and by a different `CASE` statement.  What is your desired output?

Comment: added `sql-server` tag based on the non-standard `[..]` "quoting" style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the calculations in an aggregate function  like-

```
select FirstName,
case 
when managers.title = 'GM' then SUM(isnull([TotalSalaryHours],0))-90
when managers.title = '1st' then SUM(isnull([RegHours],0)+isnull([OTHours],0)
                                +isnull([PTO],0)+isnull([HolidayHours],0))-70

 End As Over_Short
 from Hours
 join Managers on managers.Manager_id = hours.manager_id
 group by  
 FirstName
```

Comment: This worked, but let me get this straight so I understand it.  You have to use a sum, average, etc in order to group by the function?

Comment: Now instead of one person's total hours -90 for their over short.  it uses each line-90 so it inflates the total.  I need to do the case when functions after the group by sum.  working on that now.

Comment: Yep.. in your query essentially you are trying to group by FirstName, then you need to tell the query engine what to do with the other columns you have in your query.. the engine does not assume that you need to add them up.

Comment: Oops.. yep fixed that.